# What is the purpose of 'turn' in this line of code?

Tags: c++

```
enum class Turn {white, black} turn;
```

What is the purpose of 'turn' after declaring the class Turn?

Comment: ... and you discover why the `;` is required at the end. Of course that does not only concern the enum

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simply declaring a `Turn` variable. It's the same as writing:

```
enum class Turn {white, black};
Turn turn;
```